# Manipulations with dates in Sqlite3

Tags: date, sqlite

We are working with sqlite3 and have encountered one problem.

We have a database for library with several tables, in particular - items table and loans table. When we insert a new item into the loans table, we have to save the Start date and Due date of the loan. The starting date is **select Date('now')** and the Due date should be calculated as the Start date + exact number of days taken from the items table (= loanduration).
We try to do it with following query:

```
update loans set Sdate=(SELECT date('now')) where CID=NEW.CID and IID=NEW.IID;
update loans set Ddate= select date(NEW.Sdate, '+' || (select loanduration from items where items.IID=NEW.IID) where CID=NEW.CID and IID=NEW.IID day|| 'day');
```

However, it doesn`t work and we can`t find the proper solution.
Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), the modifier must be `+NNN days`:

```sql
> SELECT date('now', '+3day');

> SELECT date('now', '+3 day');
2014-03-12
```